# Как подключить домен через консоль сменить на сайте?

Tags: сервер, консоль, домен

Как подключить домен через консоль сменить на сайте. Чисто консоль есть по серверу, без ispmgr и других вещей только консоль(  мне надо домен сменить там внутри на другой как это сделать ? на https://cloud.digitalocean.com

Comment: Какое ПО стоит? В качестве веб сервера apache?

Comment: 4 GB Memory / 80 GB Disk / AMS3 - Ubuntu 16.04.3 x64

Comment: на сервере стоит apache? nginx? или просто голый Ubuntu?

Comment: Получается домен по айпи перенаправили на нужный айпи этот голый сервер там сайт лежит какая та дичь еще есть универ один домен рабочий где сайт еще есть университи и там картинка просто мол тех работы и стоит так картинка . Я так понял это разные директории в серваке и из за этого проблемы ( Что мне надо сделать ? удалить ту директорию или же прописать в самом сайте что то или в убунту?

Answer (score -1):

Если apache не установлен - устанавливаем

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

(инструкция по установки LAMP - https://losst.ru/ustanovka-lamp-ubuntu-16-04)

LAMP - это можно сказать "джентльменский набор" - Linux, Apache, MySQL, PHP

После чего настраиваем apache virtualhost

Например, для наших сайтов мы создадим директории:

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/www/example.com/public_html
```

Создание файла виртуального хоста

```
sudo cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com.conf

sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com.conf
```

И изменяем его что бы он стал похож на

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Включение нового виртуального хоста

```
sudo a2ensite example.com.conf
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Более подробная инструкция -https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/apache-ubuntu-16-04-ru

После чего настраиваем DNS зону (описание с reg ru https://www.reg.ru/support/domains/dns_servery_i_nastroika_zony/Nastroika-zony/nastroika-resursnyh-zapisei-dlya-domena)